# Interpolate data between two samples

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy, matplotlib-basemap

I have variable temperature dataset on 3 hour interval, which I plot as contour over map.
Making animation with matplotlib from this data shows abrupt sequences (as expected).

I was wondering if there is some way to interpolate 10 or more subsamples between existing two, in order to make transition smooth?

Comment: See [Interpolation (scipy.interpolate)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I don't see what is unspecific in my question. I don't want to interpolate data over grid - I want to interpolate between two samples, which in my case are obviously 2d numpy arrays.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  It sounds like you want to do 1-D interpolation over time.  Granted you want to do that for each point in a 2-D array but the interpolation part is 1-D. [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy-interpolate-interp1d) will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually solution is first grade math - subtracting the samples and dividing by desired factor gives delta value which we just add to first sample to get interpolated values:

```
delta = (t[1, :, :] - t[0, :, :]) / 10
interp_vals = [t[0, :, :] + delta * x for x in range(10)]
```

Comment: Note this is linear interpolation in 1D: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Other interpolation schemes are possible:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation